# Compare userInput JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error on the second output.

```js
var compareNumber = 3; // Code will be tested with: 3, 8, 42
var userNumber = '3'; // Code will be tested with: '3' 8, 'Hi'

/* Your Response goes Here*/

if (userNumber == compareNumber) {
  console.log('Numbers are equal\nVariables are not identical');
} else {
  console.log('Variables are not identical');
}
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: you have an extra opening curly braces **{** at the end of console

Comment: It was a typo. I corrected

Comment: This doesn't make sense though. When `compareNumber` and `userNumber` will both be `8`, they will be equal AND identical, aren't you theoretically missing an `else if` with a `===` operator?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this out for your solution.

In javascript `==` checks for the values only without type, so 3 & '3' are same for this as the value is same, although type is different, so this will return true

`===` matches both value & type both, so 3 & '3' are different here, it will return false

```js
var compareNumber = 8; // Code will be tested with: 3, 8, 42
var userNumber = 8; // Code will be tested with: '3' 8, 'Hi'

/* Your Response goes Here*/

if (userNumber === compareNumber) {
  console.log('Numbers are identical');
} else if(userNumber == compareNumber){
  console.log('Numbers are equal\nVariables are not identical');
} else {
  console.log('Variables are not identical');
}
```